# How to override default theme page in Drupal 7x

Tags: drupal

I'm creating my own theme in `drupal` with the help of zen starter kit.
It works fine and nodes are working `node--[yourthing].tpl.php`, but when i want a custom page he doesn't pick it up ore something.

I want him to over ride the standard `html.tpl.php` and pick only `html--projects.tpl.php`.
In the content area i give it an alias; projects.

So i though when u were going to `/drupal/projects` he would pick the projects.tpl but he doesn't. Or do i need to do it with `page.tpl.php`, first timer so can someone help out?

Many thx.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the problem correctly, you want to do different theming for `/drupal/projects` url.

File name for the same should be:
`page--drupal--projects.tpl.php` OR `page--drupal.tpl.php`

**Clear all cache** after making this change:

```
http://example.com/admin/config/development/performance
```